# Trigger a function call on clicking a link, returning the link value that's clicked

Tags: xslt, jquery

Basically, I'm looking to get 'URLValue' if the particular `<a>` is clicked and pass it on to another method. There are several other `<a>` elements with class="LinkClass" and I have written a JQuery to get only the clicked element value. 
Below is a working JQuery to do just this, it references the XSL.

```
 $("a.LinkClass").live("click", function() {
        var URL = $(this).attr("href");  
        //Now call another method passing this value
    });
```

However, can I use the value directly through XSL, triggering a function call on event click for the link?

XSL below:

```
 <a class="LinkClass">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="URLValue"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </a>
```

Comment: You could staticly define `a/@onclick`. If this is not what you are asking, then do note that XSLT works before any user iteraction.

Comment: I've been trying to do this. Doesn't work. Not sure what I'm missing.
Tried keeping it simple by just writing out HTML with a simple javascript method.
and doing 
<a class="LinkClass"target="_blank" onclick="function1(Page1.htm)"> Page1</a>
doesn't work.

Comment: Then, what you are trying falls out of scope of XSLT. Staticly define onclick attribute can be done in XSLT. Why that is not working into your scenario might be because of many reason. I'm wondering in wich fase you've runned the transformation.

Comment: no, just trying it in simple HTML (without XSL) is also not working. 
thought if I could get it working in HTML, I could do it similarly in XSL.
Thanks for your help. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this XML document is open on browser:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test XSLT javascript injektion</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Test XSLT javascript injektion</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this stylesheet as "test.xsl":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
     doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"/>
    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()" priority="1"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="xhtml:a/node()[1]">
        <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
            <xsl:value-of select='concat("alert(&apos;",..,"&apos;)")'/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test XSLT javascript injektion</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Test XSLT javascript injektion</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="alert('Google')">Google</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" onclick="alert('Stack Overflow')">Stack Overflow</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

And alerts works on click.

Comment: actually the XSL is not working :( the output page is working let me also try again

Comment: @Amy: If you are sending this trought the wire, take care of MIME type.

Comment: <xsl:template match="Node" mode="URL">
    <a class="URL1">
      <xsl:if test="DisplayTargetTypeID='102'">
        <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="URLvalue"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
        <xsl:value-of select='concat("ajaxws.method1(&apos;",..,"&apos;)")'/>
      </xsl:attribute>     
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: thanks...this is how I finally solved it, may be useful to someone else:        <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="URLValue"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="onclick">MethodName('<xsl:value-of select="URLValue"/>');return true;</xsl:attribute> </a>